# map with string key and string or slice value?

Tags: string, mapping, go

Newbee warning.

Can I make a map with a string key and "anything" as a value? The goal is to have a map of configuration data. This data can be either a single string (or boolean value or integer, but restricting this to a string is fine), or it can be an array of strings. Example: I'd like to store these items:

```
levels = 3
extra-directories = ["foo","bar","baz"]
```

The first option is always a single value (a string would be OK for me). The second option is zero or more values.

The goal is to have a single map where I can store these values and when looking at the map, I could use `switch x.(type)` to find out what the value is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`interface{}` is a type that accepts any type.

```
conf := map[string] interface{} {
    "name": "Default",
    "server": "localhost",
    "timeout": 120,
}
```

`conf["name"]` is an `interface{}` not a `string`, and `conf["timeout"]` is an `interface{}` not an `int`. You can pass `conf["name"]` to functions that take `interface{}` like `fmt.Println`, but you can't pass it to functions that take `string` like `strings.ToUpper`, unless you know that the `interface{}`'s value is a `string` (which you do) and assert it's type:

```
name := conf["name"].(string)
fmt.Println("name:", strings.ToUpper(name))
server := conf["server"].(string)
fmt.Println("server:", strings.ToUpper(server))
timeout := conf["timeout"].(int)
fmt.Println("timeout in minutes:",  timeout / 60)
```

---

Another solution that might fit your problem is to define a struct:

```
type Config struct {
    Name string
    Server string
    Timeout int
}
```

Create configuration:

```
conf := Config{
    Name: "Default",
    Server: "localhost",
    Tiemout: 60,
}
```

Access configuration:

```
fmt.Println("name:", strings.ToUpper(conf.Name))
fmt.Println("server:", strings.ToUpper(cnf.Server))
fmt.Println("timeout in minutes:",  conf.Timeout / 60)
```

Comment: Technically interface{} is an Interface that all types implement. It's a subtle distinction but worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that using a map having type `map[string]interface{}`.